# How to store values from DatePicker in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datepicker

I searched the whole internet and this website for the answer and nothing works. Is my question wrong? How do I actually get selected date from DatePicker and store it in a property?

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker has a property called `SelectedDate` that you should be able to read from and store.

Comment: I have this: train.DepDate = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(train.DepDate); and it displays me blank messagebox

Answer (score 0):

You can use application settings to store the values of your date times, follow these steps:

1. first you will need to create the setting, open your project in Visual Studio and go to "Project\[your app's name] Properties" menu and go to "Settings" tab.
2. now name your setting lets say "SelectedDateSet" and set it to System.DateTime type.
3. after you have a setting ready we can use the "SelectedDateChanged" event of the date picker control to save it's value's :

   ```
   private void DatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedDateSet = DatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
   }
   ```

   - DatePicker1 is the what I named the date picker control.
4. after you've saved the date values you can read it any time, try this code sample:

   `public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           DatePicker1.SelectedDate = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedDateSet;
       }`

   - here we tell the program to read the saved dates when it starts.